# Entered wrong .bash_profile and now my laptop is running hot

Tags: command-line, bash, terminal, .bash-profile

I am just learning how to use the command line and was editing the bash prompt setting in `.bash_profile`.

I made an error in the prompt settings in `.bash_profile` and I lost the prompt and the ability to enter commands in terminal.

When I did this I noticed my MacBook pro got really hot and the fan came on. I eventually fixed the `.bash_profile` settings by opening it in TextEdit by New Command `open -e .bash_profile` in terminal.

I have my prompt and use of terminal back but my laptop is still running very hot. Does anyone know what is happening and how I can fix this?

Edit:

Yes I am running OSX 10.9.4, The .bash_profile with the error was…

```
export PS1='$[\033[01;36m\]\u\[\033[01;35m\]@\h\[\033[01;33m\]:\[\033[01;31m\]\w\[\033[01;33$'
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=ExFxBxDxCxegedabagacad
alias ls='ls -GFh’
```

and after I corrected it is now:

```
export PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;36m\]\u\[\033[01;35m\]@\h\[\033[01;33m\]:\[\033[01;31m\]\w\[\033[01;33$'    
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=ExFxBxDxCxegedabagacad
alias ls='ls -GFh’
```

There are not applications running except firefox

Comment: Could you show your .bash_profile? Did you check your activity monitor for programs running with high CPU usage? Which OS are we talking about (I assume OS X)?

Comment: I have added this information to the question, thankyou

Comment: I guess you forgot to remove the $ at the beginning. 
`export PS1='[\033[01;36m]\u[\033[01;35m]@\h[\033[01;33m]:[\033[01;31m]\w[\033[01;33$'` doesn't give an error for me. The `${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}` is explained in the following post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/372849/what-does-debian-chrootdebian-chroot-do-in-my-terminal-prompt/372876#372876